# np.where returning TypeError: boolean value of NA is ambiguous when using !=

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, python-datetime

I have a table of the following

1st column = region (many different regions)

2nd column = dates (many dates, from 2020-03-12 to 2022-10-02, daily increment)

3rd column = amount of something reported

I'm given a task to calculate the weekly gain of the value in 3rd column

During the completion of the task I encountered the issue with where function from numpy, where using "!=" gives me an error but if I use <, > or equality, the error does not show. Fixing the error with fillna in the end felt very wrong. Please help

Here is my process about completing the task: I want to

1. add a column that would separate my rows by week = 'week_key'
2. group by using region and this week key, followed by summation
3. etcetc

Sadly on the very first step I'm having problems. I opted to use isocalendar function in datetime

in order to get week, but this doesn't completely solve the issue: mainly the week number across different years. I need to somehow separate them. To do this I decided to make a week_key variable as something like "year*100 + week number". Sounds good on paper, but in practice, sadly, when a week crosses new year (for example, 52nd week of 2021 has 2 days in 2022, Saturday and Sunday, respectively), my week_key value reports 202152 for first 5 days and 202252 for the remaining 2 days, which is wrong. For the remaining 2 days I also want 202152.

To solve this I decided to write somewhat complicated expression after sorting my dataframe accordingly:

```
https://shorturl.at/jlF17
```

(sorry, I just couldn't figure out how to format that via the CTRL-K, this is a pastebin link, which is also too hard to post here, apparently. I deeply apologise for the caused inconvenience)

What happens there is that basically if any of the previous 6 rows has the same week number and also has a different year, then week_key should include a previous year and as a result my Saturday and Sunday end up with 202152 respectively, as intended

Now, here is my problem: I had to add fillna at the end of each clause, because for some unknown to me reason I was getting the **TypeError: boolean value of NA is ambiguous** error otherwise. What is also interesting is that if instead of != I used, for example, ==, < or >, there would be no error.

Hence the question: why is "!=" causing the error while <, == and > does not?

Comment: `where` is only as good as `cond` array.  `a <=b`.  Test that by itself.  Some variables can't be tested for equality or size.

Comment: `NA` tests are weird.